# Invoice_id in picking

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

```py
class stock_picking(models.Model):
    _inherit = "stock.picking"

invoice_id = fields.Many2one('account.invoice', "Invoice", readonly=True)
```

In picking I want to have field invoice and that it would be filled with an associated invoice.

What method should I override and how can I link invoice_id with picking?

Comment: You've tagged two Odoo versions: 8 and 9. But both are very different in that part. In Odoo 8 you had the possibility to create invoices directly from a picking. In Odoo 9+ that's not possible anymore. So for what version is your question exactly?

Comment: ohh... then it will be for version 9.

Comment: I don't have a good solution but maybe you'll find something [in this OCA module](https://github.com/OCA/stock-logistics-workflow/tree/cf0b656149cc5931566b7126dc06304e39e36f61/stock_picking_invoice_link)